# require.js issue when used with slick.js

Tags: jquery, requirejs, slick.js

I am using require.js (2.1.15 version) for in our website (this is came as part of Sitecore MVC WFFM).
I have the slick.js in the same website. Now require.js throwing some error related to slick.js and stops all by scrupts to load and break the page.

Whats might be the is the issue here.
This is the error derails as found in browser console:

Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:

```
function ($) {
'use strict';
var Slick = window.Slick || {};
Slick = (function() {
var instanceUid = 0;
function Slick(element, settings) {
    var _ = this,
    responsiveSettings, breakpoint;
    _.defaults = {
        accessibility: true,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        appendArrows: $(element),
        appendDots: $(element),
        arrows: true,
        asNavFor: null,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none"     class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>',
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        centerMode: false,
        centerPadding
```

Thanks,
sharath